# save core data into boolean value

Tags: swift, core-data, properties, boolean, helper

In my swift code below the goal is to save a boolean value into core data. I am getting a compile error stating **Thread 1: "Unacceptable type of value for attribute: property = "bool"; desired type = NSNumber; given type = __SwiftValue; value = true."**. I don't know what to do next. I also added a photo of my core data attributes. I have 2 classes a base class and a helper class.

[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1ELa.png)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var user : [User]? = nil
        CoredataHandler.saveObject(username: "Yahs", password: "213", bool: true)
}

class CoredataHandler : NSManagedObject {
    
    
    private class func getContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    
        return appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    }
    
    
    class func saveObject(username: String,password: String,bool: DarwinBoolean) -> Bool{
        let context = getContext()
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "User", in: context)
        let managedObject = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)
        
        managedObject.setValue(username, forKey: "username")
        managedObject.setValue(password, forKey: "password")
        managedObject.setValue(bool, forKey: "bool")
        
        do {
            try context.save()
            
            return true
        } catch{
            return false
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: `bool as NSNumber`

Comment: @Max I recommend using a better name than `bool` for the attribute in your User entity. The name `bool` is too easy to confuse with Swift's `Bool` data type and doesn't tell you what the attribute represents, unlike the `username` and `password` attributes.